# GSON not deserializing object correctly

Tags: java, serialization, gson

I have a simple object that I am serializing on and iOS device, sending to an Android device, and deserializing on the Android device. The object has 3 fields an enum and 2 integers. Here is the serialized form of the object on the iOS device:

```
data = {"mTurnTimer":60,"mCreoCount":1,"mStage":"DRY_GRASS"}
```

I also see the above on the Android device as a string, but when I call

```
serializedOptions = json.fromJson(data, BattleOptions.class)
```

and print out the fields, I see the default values that are set in the constructor. I also went ahead and serialized the deserialized object just to see the output and this is what I saw:

```
json.toJson(serializedOptions)) -> {"bvu":"OCEAN","bvv":3,"bvw":120}
```

So this does not make any sense to me, since the String that is being received is structured correctly, but the output is incorrect. Any suggestions on how to correct this?

Comment: Could you provide the code for `BattleOptions` class

Comment: After a bit more digging, it turned out to be that proguard on Android was obfuscating the BattleOptions class. I added an exception in the proguard options and it all seems to work now.